# Differentiating between 2 strings using regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex

```
mato_grosso_2000_test.csv
mato_grosso_do_sul_2000_test.csv
```

I want to build a regular expression in python that can differentiate between the 2 lines above. `_20xx_test.csv` is always present in file name where `xx` can range from `00` to `17` How do I do that?

I tried a simple fnmatch but that cannot differentiate between the two i.e. mato_grosso finds mato_grosso_do_sul as well

EDIT:

I want the reg ex test to select `mato_grosso_2000_test.csv` and `mato_grosso_2001_test.csv` but not `mato_grosso_do_sul_2000_test.csv`

Comment: In other words, are you looking for an expression that matches the first string but not the second?

Comment: What do you mean by differentiate?  An re that matches the first but not the second, or matches the second and not the first, or ....?

Comment: thanks @DYZ, yes, i have edited question for clarity

Comment: `r'mato_grosso_20\d\d_test.csv'` does what you ask for. But somehow I think you want something else.

Comment: thanks @DYZ, I do want something different. The `mato_grosso` part is just an example. It could be any state e.g. colorado or any other region in the world.

Comment: Then what is a _counter_ example for the "colorado" example? What 'colorado' name should _not_ match?

Comment: so `colorado` won't have any problem because there is no other region with colorado` in the name. `mato_grosso` does because `mato_grosso_de_sul` has `mato_grosso` in the name

Comment: Your information is not sufficient. Show at least another pair of names one of which should match and the other should not. How does the regex know that "colorado" is special and "mato_grosso" is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you were really after is something that works more like this:

```
regions_to_files = defaultdict(list)
for x in filenames:
    matches = re.match(r'(?P<region>.*)_(?P<year>200[0-9]|201[0-7])_test.csv', x)
    region = matches.group('region')
    regions_to_files[region].append(x)
```

Now all files related to `mato_grosso` will be available at `regions_to_files['mato_grosso']` while all files related to `mato_grosso_do_sul` will be available at `regions_to_files['mato_grosso_do_sul']`

---

Matches the first filename:

```
# mato_grosso_2000_test.csv
re.match(r'mato_grosso_20(0[0-9]|1[0-7])_test.csv', filename)
```

Matches the second filename but not the first:

```
# mato_grosso_do_sul_2000_test.csv
re.match(r'mato_grosso_do_sul_20(0[0-9]|1[0-7])_test.csv', filename)
```

The regular expression `(0[0-9]|1[0-7])` will match 00, 01, . . . , 17 for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with a negative lookahead assertion to find matches of "mato_grosso" not followed by "do_sul".  For example:

```
re.match('mato_grosso_(?!do_sul)', 'mato_grosso_2000_test.csv')

re.match('mato_grosso_(?!do_sul)', 'mato_grosso_do_sul_2000_test.csv')
```

This finds a match for the first example, but not for the second.

The Python [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) documentation has more discussion of the regular expression syntax.  Do a find for "negative lookahead" for more details on this.